# Hyper-V Role on Server 2008 R2

Tags: security, virtualization

So I read over a dozen articles regarding Hyper-V and iSCSI (host or VM using software) and they both have pros/cons about each. However, the host-based has better performance. So now that I decided to use iSCSI on the host, i'm stuck with going with a GUI instead of core of Windows Server 2008 R2 because Drobo does not support core installs.

Being that its more resource intensive and has higher chance of attacks, what can I do to protect the server? Is the following "enough"?

1. Keep the server updated with Microsoft updates.
2. Install anti-virus/security software
3. Enable firewall and block unused ports
4. Have the host not join a domain

Comment: You seem confused... What exactly are you trying to do? Setup a Hyper-V server (cluster?) with iSCSI storage?

Comment: The Drobo is used for storing files. Not for hosting the VMs.

I have two physical servers and hosting the VM's on the local storage. I have two Drobos, one connected to each server. DFS replicates them. However, I want to virtualize the servers so I can run other applications.

Answer (score 2):

> So now that I decided to use iSCSI on the host, i'm stuck with going with a GUI instead of core of 
>   Windows Server 2008 R2 because Drobo does not support core installs.

HÄH?

ISCSI is standardized and ca nbe set up from the command line. Why do you Need a GUI on the Hyper-V Server because of Drobo not supporting core? This doesn't make sense.

> Being that its more resource intensive

Häh? A non trivial Hyper-V Server has so many ressources the 100mb or so mroe RAM needed ythe GUI is - nothing. Like NOTHING. Plus you can always use Server 2012, with gui, then remove the GUI - that is possible on 2012. Given all the HGH Advantages of the nwe Hyper-V Version, why anyone would install a old Server 2008 R2 for Hyper-V is osmething that I fail to unerstand. SHort of I do not know what I do".

> Keep the server updated with Microsoft updates.

Yes.

> Install anti-virus/security Software

What for, on a Hsper-V role? As noone except admins ever should log in and nothing except bare bones Software (Drivers, backup Agent, System Monitoring) should ever be installed on a Hyper-V Server, why have a antivirus System waste time? It will not protect the virtual machines anyway.

> Enable firewall and block unused ports

Yes. Or you make sure the Server itself has no contact outside the operational adminsitrative VLAN for Hyper-V Hosts.

> Have the host not join a Domain

Home single Server install? Wrong place here. Otherwise, sorry, run a separate Network for the infrastructure. My own small Company has a separate Domain for infrastructure, Hosting only stuff like WSUS, central file shars (ISO Images) and - Hyper-V Hosts. Access to the Hyper-V Hosts is isolated by Routing policies and a separte VLAN and Management Network.

Comment: This is a small business environment. I do not have any licenses for 2012, only 2008 R2 Standard. Not in the budget to upgrade to 2012 as of yet. The Drobo needs a GUI to administer.

Comment: I think you mean "The Drobo has a GUI with which it can be administered". That GUI is unrelated to the server GUI. I'm presuming the Drobo has a web based UI that you can access from any computer on the same network. Why would the Drobo rely on the server GUI?

Comment: The Drobo is not web based. You can see the Drobo Dashboard here: http://www.drobo.com/products/drobo-dashboard/index.php
.
If I ever need to create volumes, etc, the GUI needs to be used.

Comment: OK, so is your intention to use iSCSI on the Drobo to present LUN's to the hosts or to the guests? If to the hosts then what's the planned usage for the Drobo as it pertains to the hosts, since the guests will be on local storage of the servers. I'm at a bit of a loss to understand how exactly the Drobo fits in.

Comment: Drobo stores all our files that employees use. It replicates to the other drobo using DFS.

Comment: So it's a file share. How is it related to the Hyper-V hosts and iSCSI?